# Creating ejb project

Tags: eclipse, interface, ejb

I am trying to learn ejb by reading MasteringEJB by ED Roman. It stated there that we need to create the interface first. For example, we need to create

1.Remote interface for Hello.java

2.Local interface for HelloLocal.java

3.Home interface for HelloHome.java

4.Local Home interface for HelloLocalHome.java

5.and we need to create interface for our bean class, HelloBean.java

6.and we need to have deployment descriptor

and lastly we need to package all this file together in EJB-jar file.

so my question is , I do not know which one to choose?

like go to File>New> --which one should i choose? is it file?interface? java project? ejb?

Could anyone  help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried taking a look at the source code that goes with the book:

http://media.techtarget.com/tss/static/books/wiley/masteringEJB/downloads/3eCode.zip

Comment: thanks!!! it is not wat I looking for but this will really help me out throughout the topic because i need it though..really appreciate it :D .